# Mix usage of html/js with C#/XAML in winrt / winjs

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs

Actually, I have to use Google Maps in my app and it's in WinJS project but I am not comfortable with JS. It has associated files map.html/css/JS. Now I have to add login page with some page maintenance and cloud integration. I want to write login in c#/xaml after it so that MAP page will be called. How can I partition this(login + MAP page) and under which project ? and how to call MAP page(html/js) from login page(c#/xaml) ? Any code etc.

Thanks

Comment: Look into using the WebView: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227702 But, I don't understand how you're using a WinRT WinJS project, but asking about C#?

Comment: Actually project is winJS but I want to code in c#/xaml for login and cloud integration!

Comment: I don't know that there's a way to mix those two actually. You can host web content in either one, but WinJS and WinRT really is just using the Internet Explorer browser to host your application, so, it can't show XAML. You can definitely include C# in your application solution (in another project) and use it from WinJS.

Comment: yes you can use your c# Skills on HTML5 Winjs App,but you can't able to use your XAML with HTML5, only C# is running as backend.

Answer (score 0):

I did this my own. I placed all html/js/css code in one html file then in winRT project I used webView to show this. I just copy all that html code and assign it to a string and pass this string to WebView1.NavigateToString(string).

Comment: x-webview not fully support all HTML5 features !!